# How to retrieve values from a multi-d array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

Here is an array from an user generated course-creation system. What would be the best way to retrieve values associated with [titreSection], [lessonTitle] and [lessonContent] keys  ?

Main goal here is to allow the user to create sections that contains a title with several lessons and content associated to a section. The order and logic remains the same. Only the number of sections and [content] will change depending the structure of the created course.

Here is the foreach loop with the results

```
$course = $_POST['section'];

foreach ($course as $key=>$value){

    foreach ($value as $key1=>$value1)

        foreach ($value1 as $key2=>$value2)

            foreach ($value2 as $key3=>$value3)
               echo $key3 . '==>' . $value3 . '<br >';

}
```

From this result, how can i print out all the '[titreSection]' only ?

```
titreSection==>Section 1
lessonTitle==>Lesson 1
lessonContent==>Contenu 1
lessonTitle==>Lesson 2
lessonContent==>Contenu 2
titreSection==>Section 2
lessonTitle==>Lesson 3
lessonContent==>Contenu 3
lessonTitle==>Lesson 4
lessonContent==>Contenu 4




Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [titre] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [titreSection] => Section 1
                        )

                )

            [contenu] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [lessonTitle] => Lesson 1
                            [lessonContent] => Contenu 1
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [lessonTitle] => Lesson 2
                            [lessonContent] => Contenu 2
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [titre] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [titreSection] => Section 2
                        )

                )

            [contenu] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [lessonTitle] => Lesson 3
                            [lessonContent] => Contenu 3
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [lessonTitle] => Lesson 4
                            [lessonContent] => Contenu 4
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: probably want to start with a loop such as `foreach()` but its hard to say more than that

Comment: Don't use variable names like `$value`, `$value1`, `$value2` and `key`, `key1`, `key2`. Doing so rapidly gets confusing and makes your code hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could probably start you off in the right direction. I've assumed your data is in an array called `$sections`. Note that you have inconsistent index values in your data (`lessonTitle` and `titreLesson`) I've assumed they are all `titreLesson`.

```
foreach ($sections as $section) {
    echo "<h2>{$section['titre'][1]['titreSection']}</h2>\n";
    foreach ($section['contenu'] as $lesson) {
        echo "<h3>{$lesson['titreLesson']}</h3>\n";
        echo "<p>{$lesson['lessonContent']}</p>\n";
    }
}
```

Output

```
<h2>Section1</h2>
  <h3>Lesson1</h3>
    <p>Contenu1</p>
  <h3>Lesson2</h3>
    <p>Contenu2</p>
<h2>Section2</h2>
  <h3>Lesson3</h3>
    <p>Contenu3</p>
  <h3>Lesson4</h3>
    <p>Contenu4</p>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/JWPMe)

Comment: Thanks, my initial foreach loop was not detailed enough to retrieve specific data. thanks again.